# Context.Request.GetHttpContext() returns null in SignalR server for browser capabilities

Tags: web-applications, signalr, signalr-hub, httpbrowsercapabilities

I'm trying to get Browser capabilities and remote IP address of the client from the SignalR server. I have used `Context.Request.GetHttpContext()` as per many suggestions instead of `HttpContext.Current`. But, I am still getting 'null'. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't explain why the httprequest returns null but `Context.Request.Environment` contains remote IP of the client and handfull of other information about the connection. Hope it helps.